# Android converting string to array string

Tags: java, android, regex, arrays, string

I have a string like this:

```
["477","com.dummybilling","android.test.purchased","inapp:com.dummybilling:android.test.purchased","779"]
```

How to have a String[] with these 5 element?
Does anyone know a regex for `.split()` method?

Thank you very much, regular expressions make me crazy! :(

Comment: Why don't you use a JSON parser?

Comment: What exactly you want ?

Comment: @BackSlash I 'm trying with JSON: I convert it into JSONArray, but then I'm catching some exaption with take out string value from json object...

Comment: @Jitesh Dalsaniya I would like to have an array of string from this string: `["data1","data2","data3","data4","data5"]`

Comment: This array is JSON Array or simple one?

Comment: @Jitesh Dalsaniya it was an JSONArray converted into a string, but Ravi Thapliyal give me the solution. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Process it as JSON. Two immediate benifits would be that it would take care of any embedded commas in your data automatically and the other that you would get a `String[]` with *unquoted* strings.

```
String input = "[\"477\",\"com.dummybilling\",\"android.test.purchased\",\"inapp:com.dummybilling:android.test.purchased\",\"779\"]";

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(input);
String[] strArr = new String[jsonArray.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    strArr[i] = jsonArray.getString(i);
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArr));
```

***Output** :*

```
[477, com.dummybilling, android.test.purchased, inapp:com.dummybilling:android.test.purchased, 779]
```

Comment: @Tarsem, yes mate. Did you run into any problems? Works fine at my end.

Comment: yup but i fixed :) +1 for exact and proper solution.

Comment: @Tarsem, now try with commas like `4,7,7`. Isn't that cool? :)

Comment: yup tried, its cool :) `o/p` => `4,7,7`

Comment: There's target for KITKAT - `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)`

Answer (score 2):

You can split your string by separator `["` (the beginning) or `","` or `"]` (the ending) like this:

```
final String[] tokens = yourString.split("\",\"|\\[\"|\"\\]");
```

Please note that this will only work for your string. It's not a general solution (for example, it does not take care of any escaped quotes). If your string is in JSON format, you should use a JSON parser as proposed by @Ravi Thapliyal .